# PHP COM File Not found after RegAsm a COM dll

Tags: php, .net, com, regasm

I Create a VB.NET COM Object. Register It with RegAsm and load it in PHP.

On my Computer(WIndows 7) it work like a charm ! But On my Server

> Windows Server 2016 PHP COM class say File Not Found...

I check regedit on the server and everything should fine.

Some people have this king of problem ?

I Output the .reg file

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\PISDKPHP.PISDKPHP]
@="PISDKPHP.PISDKPHP"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\PISDKPHP.PISDKPHP\CLSID]
@="{709415B5-3D12-455C-9B03-EB1F8B494525}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{709415B5-3D12-455C-9B03-EB1F8B494525}]
@="PISDKPHP.PISDKPHP"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{709415B5-3D12-455C-9B03-EB1F8B494525}\InprocServer32]
@="mscoree.dll"
"ThreadingModel"="Both"
"Class"="PISDKPHP.PISDKPHP"
"Assembly"="PISDKPHP, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
"RuntimeVersion"="v4.0.30319"
"CodeBase"="file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/PISDKPHP/PISDKPHP.dll"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{709415B5-3D12-455C-9B03-EB1F8B494525}\InprocServer32\1.0.0.0]
"Class"="PISDKPHP.PISDKPHP"
"Assembly"="PISDKPHP, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
"RuntimeVersion"="v4.0.30319"
"CodeBase"="file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/PISDKPHP/PISDKPHP.dll"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{709415B5-3D12-455C-9B03-EB1F8B494525}\ProgId]
@="PISDKPHP.PISDKPHP"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{709415B5-3D12-455C-9B03-EB1F8B494525}\Implemented Categories\{62C8FE65-4EBB-45E7-B440-6E39B2CDBF29}]
```

Answer (score 0):

My Bad, it's juste a problem with Misconfigured .NET framework ^^